# Automatically inserting datetime with insert

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid with the setup below. I'm able to properly insert a new row into my table but the `Time_Stamp` column still shows as `NULL`. Datatype is `datetime` in the database. I've tried including the `Time_Stamp` in my `Insert` query but still get `NULL` on the other side.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid_ValueCard" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlValueCard" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" Width="750px"  Skin="WebBlue" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" DataSourceID="SqlValueCard" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
        <CommandItemSettings ShowCancelChangesButton="True" ShowSaveChangesButton="True" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProviderID" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter ProviderID column" HeaderText="ProviderID" SortExpression="ProviderID" UniqueName="ProviderID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AdditionalReports" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter AdditionalReports column" HeaderText="AdditionalReports" SortExpression="AdditionalReports" UniqueName="AdditionalReports">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SurveyCompleted" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter SurveyCompleted column" HeaderText="SurveyCompleted" SortExpression="SurveyCompleted" UniqueName="SurveyCompleted">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UniqueReportRequests" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter UniqueReportRequests column" HeaderText="UniqueReportRequests" SortExpression="UniqueReportRequests" UniqueName="UniqueReportRequests">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Time_Stamp" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter Time_Stamp column" HeaderText="Time_Stamp" SortExpression="Time_Stamp" UniqueName="Time_Stamp">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Here is my `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlValueCard" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RTMD_MSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1 ProviderID, AdditionalReports, SurveyCompleted, UniqueReportRequests, Time_Stamp FROM ProviderValueCard"
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ProviderValueCard] ([ProviderID], [AdditionalReports], [UniqueReportRequests], [SurveyCompleted]) VALUES (@ProviderID, @AdditionalReports, @UniqueReportRequests, @SurveyCompleted)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProviderID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="AdditionalReports" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UniqueReportRequests" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SurveyCompleted" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Your SQL DataSource does not have a Time_Stamp component.

Comment: It needs to be automatically inserted. Do I include it with the columns? surely I dont need to include it after VALUES because it doesn't need to be manually insertable?

Comment: I would have the database do it.   But if the user needs to see it before it is inserted, add it as an Insert Parameter in the DataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up your `TIME_STAMP` column to have a **default constraint** that would set the current date and time automatically when a new row is inserted:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ProviderValueCard
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ProviderValueCard_Time_Stamp
   DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()) FOR TIME_STAMP
```

Now, every time a row is inserted and no value is provided from the front-end, SQL Server will fill in the current date & time into `TIME_STAMP` automagically :-)