# Default constraint to automatically change a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `ProviderValueCard`. Is it possible to set up a default constraint to when a new row is created, if column `SessionsProgress` is > 0 then automatically set the value of the entry for column `SurveyCompleted` = 1 and set it = 0 if SessionProgress = 0?

So psedo: If SessionsProgress > 0, then SurveyCompleted = 1 else SurveyCompleted = 0

I got the idea from marc_s answer on this question: [Automatically inserting datetime with insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550932/asp-net-sql-server-automatically-inserting-datetime-with-insert)

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521546/how-to-create-default-constraint-dependent-other-column-in-sql-server

Comment: @abatishchev - You beat me to it.. you could also use a trigger for this, but computed seems to be the way to go.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you need a trigger (comments are allows only 1 per 15 seconds) (:

Comment: For the trigger :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Awesome find. What is the syntax though if I want a ">" when using it here, I get a syntax error on the >: `ALTER TABLE ProviderValueCard ADD SurveyCompleted AS CASE [SessionsProgress] WHEN > '0' THEN 1
                                                                             WHEN '0' THEN 0
                                     END`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to abatishchev, here's what worked. I couldn't figure out the > syntax error :/. I didn't have anything in that column that mattered yet, so dropping it wasn't an issue.

```
    ALTER TABLE ProviderValueCard DROP COLUMN SurveyCompleted

ALTER TABLE ProviderValueCard ADD SurveyCompleted AS CASE [SessionsProgress] WHEN '1' THEN 1
WHEN '2' THEN 1
WHEN '3' THEN 1
WHEN '4' THEN 1
WHEN '5' THEN 1
WHEN '0' THEN 0
END
```

Comment: Couldn't you just say `WHEN '0' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END`?

Comment: And when they enter as 6?

Answer (score 0):

You get that behavior with bit

```
  declare @bit bit;
  set @bit = 0;
  print @bit;
  set @bit = 1;
  print @bit;
  set @bit = 2;
  print @bit;
  set @bit = 2000;
  print @bit;
```